# Document review tool

Tags: javascript, php, collaboration, review

I want to create  document review tool.
With this tool a user can be able to upload a document and select the list of reviewer who can review the document and suggest the changes.

Problem 1:
There can be multiple user who will be reviewing the document not necessary at the same time.How to achieve concurrency.

Problem 2:
How to keep track of changes that has been suggested and make those changes available for author(who had uploaded the original document) for acceptance.

please suggest solutions .

Answer (score 3):

This is far from a trivial problem. Dagon's comment is right. You should really consider Google Docs (which has taken years to reach maturity to solve basically just this problem).

If you really want to develop it yourself, you could try wrapping a UI around `git` and using a different branch for each submission. Then show a `git diff` to the document owner to let them review changes. You could try wrapping `git add -p` (patch mode) to only accept certain line changes while rejecting others.

Keep in mind that `git` won't work very well for anything but plaintext, though, since `diff`ing binaries isn't pretty.

And in this case, you'd be better off just using Github ;)

Comment: http://nytimes.github.io/ice/demo/ I had found this ,it is online text editor. Here I am able to upload the documents using local server for editing , the problem I am facing is that I am not able to track the changes made by the reviewer of the document. Can you suggest something ?@jeff@Dagon

Comment: They're using a `diff`ing algorithm which is, as I said, far from trivial. That's why I recommend wrapping an existing version control system such as `git`. Otherwise, do some research on how those work and come back here with specific questions.

Comment: Another option: Google Docs tracks every single keypress in a database. That's pretty ambitious to tackle on your own. Just figured I'd mention it since it's a more detailed approach than simply running a `diff` between files.

Comment: If I a use vbscript is it will be helpful. And using vbscript how can I consolidate comments from different copy of same documents in to one having comments from all copy at proper place.@jeff